# how can I get more exact decimal numbers using readWorksheetFromFile?

Tags: r, import, xls, xlconnect

I am importing a .xls file in to R using the `XLConnect` package (do not want to deal with `gdata` and the `perl` executable). But `readWorksheetFromFile` is rounding to the first decimal point. I read the documentation and look around but could not find an option to control the precision of numbers.

Comment: I am importing and old excel file (.xls)

Comment: Can you convert it / them to csv? That would probably be a better route.

Comment: I ended up using another package: rio. It worked great.